# Facing - 'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data'

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, express, mern

I am sending my registration form data using an event function postData() which gets triggered when clicked on the submit button.In the react code , at register route i am sending the user data.Also mentioned line numbers in the comment -

```
   const postData = async(event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();

    const { name, email, phone, work, password, cpassword} = user;

    const response = await fetch('/register' , {
        method: 'POST',
        headers : {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: name,
            email : email,
            phone : phone,
            work : work,
            password: password,
            cpassword : cpassword
        })
    });

    console.log('1'); //line 44!!!!

    const data = await response.json();

    console.log('1'); //line 48

    if(data){
        console.log('1'); //line 51

        window.alert("registration successful");
        console.log("registration successful");
        history.push('/login');

    }else{   //line 57!!!!

        console.log('1'); //line 58

        window.alert("Invalid registration");
        console.log("Invalid registration");
    }
    console.log('1');   //line 63

}
```

And in my express code i am storing it in the db -

```
router.post('/register' , (req,res)=>{

const {name, email, phone, work, password, cpassword} = req.body;

//we are checking if any of the inputs are empty or not
if(!name || !email || !phone || !work || !password || !cpassword){
    return res.status(422).send('Please Fill All The Fields');
}

//we are observing if a user already registered or not by checking it's email
User.findOne({email : email})
        .then((userExist) =>{
                if(userExist){
                    return res.status(422).send('Email already exists');
                }else if(password !== cpassword){
                    return res.status(422).send('Passwords are not matching');
                }

                //if the email dont exist , that means the user is new and we will store it's data in the DB
                const user = new User({
                    name : name,
                    email : email,
                    phone : phone,
                    work : work,
                    password : password,
                    cpassword : cpassword,
        });

            

//saved the stored data in the DB
            user.save()
            .then(()=>{
                res.status(201).send('User registered Successfully')
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                res.status(500).send(err);
            })

    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
})
```

I am able to store the user data in the database but i am not able to see the alert as well as the console message in the console.And also i have used the useHistory hook to redirect to the login page after registration , but i am not getting redirected to it.In the console , i am facing this error and also added 'console.log('1')' to check whether the code is running or not.But after the line 44 console , i am facing the error at line 57.

[image]

I am still learning about mern developing so i am still a newbie.Please help me resolve this issue.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sending back a string like 'User registered Successfully' is not proper JSON.  '"User registered Successfully"'   is proper JSON

Comment: @RexHenderson Thank you , i got to learn something new today.

Comment: Well done Bhavesh! That's what SO is all about! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things here:

Either:

```
return res.status(422).send({message: 'Passwords are not matching'});
```

or

```
return res.status(422).json("Passwords are not matching");
```

If you use the first option in the front-end you can access the message using **data.message**

Comment: Thank you for answering @voxtool , now i understood what was my error.Really appreciate it!